# Removing a node in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Not sure why this is not working, JSON is all correct as proof in other firebase related methods.

```
var loggedInUserMatches = firebase.database().ref('users/' + _LOGGED_IN_USER[0].useruid + '/matches/' + 'PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2');

loggedInUserMatches.remove();
```

This does nothing and then when I console log out `loggedInUserMatches` it gives me: `U {w: sf, path: L, n: De, Oc: false, then: undefined…} "liu"`

Think perhaps I am not removing quite the right thing, any ideas?

Comment: It's going to be hard to say anything specific here. The first thing that comes to mind is: does the user have write permission to the location? If they do, can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Try using `$remove` instead of `remove`.